# download limits on iCloud Photos?

Tags: icloud

I have a large video file (15GB) on iCloud Photos. I recorded it with my iPhone, and I still see it in Photos, however if I try to airdrop it to my Mac, it says "downloading" forever and then it stops.
So I think the original was uploaded to iCloud, and the copy I have on iPhone is a lower resolution one.

I need the original for video editing, so I've tried several times to download it
from iCloud (using Safari on my Mac) and Firefox. It doesn't work. I can see that only the first 10GB or so are downloaded, and then I get the message "Connection was lost" and it stops. It is not possible to resume the download (if I try, in finder I can see the file become a 4KB file).

Any idea whether there are restrictions on Max download sizes on iCloud? I've asked my internet provider if they apply any limits, and they don't.

Am I locked out of my file forever?

Answer (score 1):

A few things...

1. You can try "Save to Files" (Save to the "On My iPhone" section to avoid re-uploading to iCloud Drive), then when it's saved there you can try to AirDrop it. This would split the two operations to ensure the download and the AirDrop don't interfere.
2. You could set up iCloud Photos on your Mac and try to download it that way. Create a separate user account if you have multiple iCloud accounts or it's not your primary machine, etc.
3. You can request a photo library dump from privacy.apple.com. No idea what will happen but it's more equipped to download large files.

All of these issues sound more like network issues on your side or a combination of problems resulting in the connection dropping. iCloud wouldn't be limiting download size, at least not intentionally.

Lastly, you could always reach out to Apple if you continue to experience issues as they may have more insight into internal processes.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, however 1) has the same problem, while 2) and 3) require downloading too much stuff. I only need that one video file.

Comment: If you choose Optimize Storage when setting up the iCloud Photos on your Mac then it won't download the entire library, no idea whether it will fix your problem though